# Handwriting is to illegible as drawing is to what?

Tags: single-word-requests

If your handwriting is illegible, then you can not understand what word is written.

But if you have not drawn well then you can not understand what is being drawn.

What word do I use for this?

Edit: The objects being drawn here are TV, cars, clocks, etc. The drawing of the TV does not look like a TV

Comment: perhaps *unclear*?  *indistinct* is rather different -- more like "out of focus", but it could be relevant.  *vague* could be helpful here.

Comment: They're not really the same things.  If legible, handwriting can be read and communicates to the reader who speaks the same language.  Art is not direct communication but is interpreted.  So who's qualified to say whether a piece of art is good or bad?

Comment: What if i am drawing real objects. Like a TV or a car...?

Comment: Kristina has made a good point. Before we can answer, you need to explain what sort of drawing (an engineering drawing? a realistic portrait?) is being attempted. You also need to say what you mean by 'understanding' a drawing. EDIT - I typed this before seeing your latest comment. Even so I think we need more information about the type of drawing and what criteria are being used to judge it.

Comment: I have updated the description.

Comment: How about "scribble?"  It looks like scribbling.

Comment: Is this type of questions from a SAT book?  Would be very much interested to know this.

Comment: @rogermue - I'm not aware whether or not this is from a SAT book. This came up in an essay I'm writing.

Comment: "incomprehensible" would also work, but Hocking's suggestion is pretty much perfect.

Comment: The drawing is crap? ;-)

Comment: In architecture school we commonly referred to drawings (as well as architectural designs themselves) as being "illegible". This is probably a legacy of Foucault and the structuralist practice of reading architecture (and much else) as 'texts', but it seems to have entered common usage.

Comment: A comment on all the answers given so far: illegible means 'writing that is difficult to read'. None of the answers so far are restricted to drawings or art or things or really anything. Inscrutable, unrecognizable, incomprehensible, etc can apply to a person's face, a bird song, an idea. I'm not saying those words are not usable for a drawing, they just aren't specific to drawings as illegible is to writing.

Comment: *postmodernism*

Comment: @seanakabry not Foucault - "The Technic of Mechanical Drafting a Practical Guide to Neat, Correct, and Legible Drawing" by Charles William Reinhardt 1900 is a famous one, possibly leading the peak in https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=legible+drawing&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clegible%20drawing%3B%2Cc0  and 'legible' is by far the most appropriate for technical drawings

Comment: Thanks for the correction @PeteKirkham. Perhaps my comment should apply only to buildings if anything: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reading+architecture&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creading%20architecture%3B%2Cc0

Comment: I was going to say *Indistinguishable* as the corollary for illegible, but with the edit of a given example, *unrecognisable* is most definitely the correct term.

Comment: "If your handwriting is illegible, then you can not understand what word is written." -- I'd say that if your writing is illegible, you can understand it, it's others who can't.

Comment: I would say "Modern", for example that looks like Modern art.

Comment: "Obscure" is the word you're looking for. The painting is obscure.

Comment: You could also use "obfuscate". The drawing is obfuscated.

Comment: "Abstruse" would also work. (sorry I can't answer your question so I'm commenting)

Comment: *Obscure* might work, but in my experience it refers to something most people never encounter in normal life. So a television might be an obscure type of technology to a 25th century human, but the drawing of the television is just bad because even someone who should know what it is, doesn't. *Obfuscate* implies intentionally hiding information. And I think *abstruse* usually implies a very technical subject that requires a great deal of study to understand.

Comment: Rorschach? Jackson Pollock?

Answer (score 109):

I would say the drawing is [unrecognizable](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=define%3Aunrecognizable):

> un·rec·og·niz·a·ble (*adjective*) — not able to be recognized or identified.

Comment: This is close but I'm not sure it's perfect. An illegible document can't be read, the information contained within it cannot be gathered. In the case of a painting it might be equivalent to say that the representation of a certain object within the painting is unrecognizable,  but does it mean the same thing to say that the painting is unrecognizable.

Comment: This one is making me think a lot.  If I call something "unrecognizable," I usually mean it doesn't look like itself, not that it doesn't look like something else.  Like, "after her makeover, Cinderella was unrecognizable."  Or, after the vandals got to it, the famous paining was unrecognizable.  I'm not sure I would use it about one thing that is supposed to, but doesn't, look like another.

Comment: Unrecognisable usually means, that the visual process by which you are viewing some thing (perhaps a person, car, drawing, animal, house - or any thing) is of low quality such that you cannot recognise what the thing is.  ("Steve is unrecognisable in this photo.")  As both Dave and Vstrong suggest.

Comment: Based on the edit which have given an example, unrecognisable is the correct option.

Comment: The only downside is that *unrecognisable* is not exclusive to visual recognition, it could be equally used for music or remembering a person's tone of voice. But still, it is the best option for an analogue to *illegible* in that it refers to a failure to match what is perceived by the senses to a pre-existing 'image' of an object in the mind with which what is seen could be compared to.

Comment: @BenjaminR, thank you, but I also think that indecipherable, unintelligible, indiscernible, and incomprehensible are equally good. Inscrutable is also an excellent choice, especially if one were considering art that is not necessarily meant to convey an image (in which case it would possibly be the best choice).

Comment: Unrecognizable means to me that you know what it is supposed to look like, but it has been damaged in some way and now you can't recognize it. (Referring to the image itself, not what the image is of.)

Answer (score 54):

You might say that the drawing is "**indecipherable**", which is defined by [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/indecipherable) as "impossible to read or understand : not decipherable".

Comment: I'd have gone with "crap"

Comment: I feel like indecipherable implies writing, and all the definitions at your link agree with this impression.

Answer (score 52):

I would go for ***inscrutable***. There are many words that do the trick, and a lot of good answers, but I think inscrutable works particularly well. In fact, the first example in Webster's definition refers specifically to art!

> **inscrutable**
>
> *adjective*
>
> \in-ˈskrü-tə-bəl\
>
> not readily investigated, interpreted, or understood
>
> *an inscrutable work of art*

*Source: [Merriam-Webster.com](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/inscrutable)*

Oxford dictionary has this to say:

> "inscrutable. impossible to understand or interpret"
>
> Oxford dictionary, Mac edition

Comment: I'd think that "an inscrutable work of art" refers more often to the intention or interpretation behind the art. That is, a still-life of an object that's intentionally done in a strange, hard-to-parse style might be inscrutable, while someone who was actually trying to draw an accurate rendering of the object but didn't succeed in conveying what it looked like doesn't feel inscrutable to me.

Comment: @Dougal, Yes, I think you bring up an excellent use of *inscrutable*, which as you point out is probably more common. I do think being unable to determine the subject (not just the meaning) of the art is still inscrutable, however.

Comment: I agree with Dan's usage of inscrutable - indeed his usage is the "original" usage, and the more usual usage (basically "a person with a blank expression") is a derivative of that.

Comment: @JoeBlow Inscrutable is not a visual analogue for *illegible*, but rather describes a specific characteristic or property completely distinct from visual recognition. It denotes the inability of an object to be comprehended by a subject – it's much more nuanced than *unrecognisable* which is a term bound with the notion of recognition and representation to the senses. *Inscrutable* has famously been used to refer to the impregnability of persons of Irish descent to (Freudian) psychotherapy, for example.

Comment: Hi Benjamin. As I said just above, and to expand by a few words: I agree with Dan's usage of inscrutable - indeed his usage is the "original" usage, and the now-more-usual usage, the more metaphoric usage (that is to say, used in relation to emotions, thoughts, Irish's people's psychoses, etc) is a derivative of that.  (The word just means "can't find" if we think etymologically.)  Nevertheless I enjoyed your erudite writing, although we disagree.

Comment: In any event, as I already explained, **the correct answer to the question is simply and only 'unclear'**.  Only one highly intelligent (and attractive) respondent gives the correct answer, below.  "inscrutable" is an interesting novelty answer; the actual answer is just "unclear".

Answer (score 41):

Or, perhaps, [unintelligible](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/unintelligible), which works for representational art and might also work if one were referring to non-representational art.

Comment: Well it works in both cases, doesn't it?

Comment: Agreed.  I meant "more appropriate than some other words," not "more appropriate for non-representational art than for representational art," though I see now what I wrote is ambiguous that way,

Comment: Definition I find of intelligible at Dictionary.com is "capable of being understood; comprehensible; clear."  I'd say this answer nails it.

Comment: Interesting, but personally, I generally associate *unintelligible* with audible communication, even though it isn't strictly defined in such a manner. This just seems to be the most common usage I've encountered - unintelligible speech of some form or another. I think examples of its usage in non-verbal areas are a bit more idiomatic, such as addressing what a painting is trying to *say*. I have nothing against this response in general, I'm just not sure it *feels* right in the context of this particular question.

Comment: unintelligible means **impossible to understand**.  it only makes sense when a meaning is attempting to be communicated.  So, a sentence can be unintelligible.  in contrast a single character (like "d") is **not** trying to communicate a message, it's a single symbol - which may be unclear.

Comment: Maybe.  The whole question sort of presupposes that one can make an analogy between writing and a drawing, though.  And we do speak of being unable to understand, for example, behavior or emotion. . . .

Answer (score 30):

I would personally go for

> Incomprehensible

Adjective, not able to be understood; not intelligible.

Comment: That's what I wanted to answer, too.

Comment: incomprehension relates to comprehension ... not understanding the meaning of a symbol.

Answer (score 22):

I would say it's **indiscernible** or **unintelligible**.

Other suggestions have unwanted connotations, like:

- *incomprehensible* implies that there is a meaning, and not comprehending it is the viewers fault. It might be *incomprehensible, but not badly drawn.*
- *indecipherable* also implies that we just can't get down to the meaning of the painting. Painting might be *indecipherable but not badly drawn.*
- *inscrutable* implies that we could, in the future, actually understand the painting. Painting might be *inscrutable but not badly drawn.*
- *unrecognizable* implies that there is a template we recognize it as, while more abstract paintings might be *unrecognizable, but not badly drawn.*

PS:

Actually **unintelligible** also might be, maybe, fitting to the wrong-connotation category. So the main suggestion would be **indiscernible**.

PPS:

Maybe just **ugly**?

Comment: +1 for indiscernible, but I would prefer to see an explanation why your suggestion works, instead of explaining why suggestions by other users don't work as well as yours (in fact there are some fine suggestions among those as well).

Comment: Well, I'm just answering the question. While it might seem like i'm attacking other users, I just know all the words in other answers, and actually it's quite an exhaustive list, as far as I know. Really, if I were to make a list of my own, it'd be just the same. Ok, I didn't know _inscrutable_.

Comment: This is my first answer, please be unapologetically brutal.

Comment: Brutal? Not my style, sorry :-). But I did forget to say welcome to the ELU :-)

Comment: I see :) Thank You. Feel free to improve my answer or criticize.

Comment: This was the word I was thinking.

Comment: For art, perhaps **ugly** is the most apropos...

Answer (score 8):

I think the best solution to this SWR is indeed simply

## unclear

Note that, of course and obviously, the OP means **ordinary representational** ("non artistic", let's say) **drawings**.

Imagine, say, a board game where you have to draw an object (cat, dog, car, house - whatever) and the other players have to guess what it is.  Or, the line drawings of objects in small children's books.  Or playing Scribblenauts.

I feel in that situation, you'd say things like "It's unclear what you've drawn!" "I have no idea what that drawing is!" "What the heck were you trying to draw here?"

That milieu is the most analogous in the question as actually put, **"Handwriting is to illegible as drawing is to what?"**

Really, "unclear" is the only word that works there, I think.

If, as many folks have commented, the OP meant Jackson Pollock paintings, the whole question is vague and should be deleted.  The question ("Handwriting is to illegible as drawing is to what?") **is only meaningful** if you're talking about "drawings" in the sense of straightforward line drawings of things.

---

**Unrecognisable** is wrong because it usually means, that the visual process by which you are viewing some thing (perhaps a person, car, drawing, animal, house - or any thing) is of low quality such that you cannot recognise what the thing is.  This is utterly unrelated to the drawing being so "bad" that it is not clear which object is being suggested (ie - "unclear").

**indecipherable** applies more to "reading' (see the dictionary definition; note "ciphers".  if the word was more like "in-line-able" it would be suitable here.)

**unintelligible** means impossible to understand. it only makes sense when a meaning is attempting to be communicated. So, a sentence can be unintelligible. in contrast a single character (like "d") is not trying to communicate a message, it's a single symbol - which may be unclear

Comment: I want to clarify, I used the question statement "Handwriting is to illegible as drawing is to what?" because that was the only way I could describe in brief what I wanted to ask. The real description of my question is in the body. If you feel the question statement should be changed, please let me know. :)

Comment: Your "real description" exactly matches the question in the headline. This is the correct answer.

Comment: I really don't think this is it. If a drawing is unclear, then I'm not sure what it *means*, not what it *is*. I went to Germany recently. There was a sign with a blue car and a red car next to each other on the highway. I could tell they were cars, but we found the sign unclear, at least at first. Later we realized it meant no passing.

Comment: Hi DC.  If you described that as "unclear," you were using the word "unclear" incorrectly, perhaps bizarrely.  Unclear means ............ un ... clear.  You just clearly and utterly stated that (utterly, spectacularly, clearly) the drawings in question were of a blue car and a red car. (I'm sure these were as *clear* as the modern german school of iconography and sign making could make them - which is about as clear as anything in this universe.) You didn't know what this sign **meant**.

Answer (score 7):

Illegible is, in fact, often used.

Drawings are read like texts (especially by Art Historians). For this context, the drawing is attempting to participate in a narrative ("it's a car!"), and failing, out of incompetence.

The drawing is supposed to be a noun, but it's not: it's illegible.

Comment: Most technical drawings are read like drawings, not like text - they are not narrative nor linear. Using 'read' and 'legible' for drawings predates its use in art https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BIs7AQAAMAAJ&q=%22read+a+drawing%22&dq=%22read+a+drawing%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CB8Q6AEwAGoVChMIzZX0pbeDyAIVgkAaCh3yww3Y

Comment: That... is an awesome link.

Answer (score 2):

**Scribble** seems the most descriptive word for a bad or unrecognizable drawing.

Comment: But scribble is a noun (or verb), whereas illegible is an adjective.

Comment: @randal'thor:  Scribblism?  :-)

Comment: I think *scribble* refers to the speed and care given to the drawing, not to how recognisable it is.

Comment: It is the wrong part of speech, but I do think this is the best answer that gets to the nuance. *Illegible handwriting* nearly always means that the handwriting was not written well or with care, which is exactly the notion that a scribble brings to a drawing.  To make it the right part of speech ***scribbled*** would work.

Comment: @MarkLakata I totally agree, and I upvoted it on day one (I'm glad to see it back to even).  Maybe if it had a few more syllables (like "scribble-scrabble/d") it would have been better received!

Comment: A scribbled piece of art doesn't mean we can't tell what it is. It just means it lacks finesse and detail, usually for the sake of being done quickly. The same word applies to text. "I scribbled some quick notes" implies you didn't copy the presentation word-for-word, but got just enough detail to reconstruct the main points.

Comment: Scribble correctly describes one particular type of drawing, which is so messy, it is unclear.  But there are various reasons a drawing can be unclear, other than, it being a scribbled.

Answer (score 2):

Your drawing is **confusing**

Simple, yes?

Answer (score 0):

“**[Hieroglyphic/hieroglyphical](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-definition/hieroglyphic)**”:
adj
1 …; 2 … ; 3    difficult to read or decipher.

noun
4  …; 5    a symbol or picture that is difficult to read or decipher.

(from English Collins Dictionary via Reverso/net)

(Granted however, it seems to work for both writing and drawing, making “Handwriting is to hieroglyphic/al as drawing is to hieroglyphic/al” yet another one of my pointless observations.)

Comment: I don't think this works. Many hieroglyphics have perfectly recognizable images of cats, people, eyes etc.

Comment: @MartinSmith By ellipting the definitions refering to the symbols used in ancient Egypt(Defs 1,2,& 4) (which I agree are often/usually perfectly recognizable), I was trying to direct attention to the more figurative, [unclear or unreadable signs or writing](http://www.wordcentral.com/cgi-bin/student?hieroglyphic), meaning of the word (Def 3 on Word Central & Defs 3&5 on Reverso/Collins). I agree with Mitch ‘s comment under the question & thought that maybe “hieroglyphic/al,” with “unclear/unreadable/indecipherable” built in (& relating specifically to signs/pictures) could address his concern.

Answer (score 0):

**Uninterpretable**

Everyone interprets art differently. If the art was to be "illegible", it could not be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

For a drawing, the word ***inappreciable*** might be suited.

Answer (score 0):

The drawing he made was [**unfathomable**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/unfathomable)

> **adjective**
>   1. not able to be [fathomed](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/fathom), or completely understood; incomprehensible:

Answer (score 0):

***inaccessible*** is another word specifically used for art (as opposed to, say, a drawing of a roadsign or something literal). 
["(Of language or an artistic work) difficult to understand or appreciate."](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/inaccessible)

Along with the usual ***unrecognizable, indiscernible, unintelligible*** which people have cited.

Answer (score 0):

I voted for *unrecognizable*, but I wanted to add a simpler wording:

> The drawing is bad.
>   This is badly drawn.
>   The drawing is crap. (from RemarkLima's comment)

Substitute *draw* with *paint* or another art method as needed. Note that this only works if it's hard to recognize because it's badly drawn. A photograph of an [exploding egg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9QtEA.jpg) might be hard to recognize while being perfectly accurate.

Something to point out here, is that there isn't actually a direct correlation between drawing and writing here. Writing uses a set of very standardized symbols that have very specific meanings, and those symbols are arranged in very specific ways with very specific syntax. Certainly, there's a great deal of allowable variation in writing, but it follows the rules.

With drawing, it's always abstract. How one person perceives a television can be very different from how another person perceives it. With a highly detailed attempt at photo-realism, it's likely most humans will tend to converge on a very similar representation (given enough skill of course) because we basically see a bitmap, and are capable of conveying data in that form.

But if we're talking about relatively simple drawings, we internally caricaturize external objects based on the aspects we consider important. To one artist who grew up in the 70s to 80s, a television could be characterized by things like the channel and volume knobs, and being shaped like a big box. To someone who's growing up now, a television could be more akin to a painting hung on the wall. And our drawings will reflect those differences.

But, because drawings are things we tend to share with, and learn from, others, we will tend to standardize them implicitly. So people who grew up together might tend to draw one aspect of something and to the people around them it's quite obvious what they drew, while an outsider might just see ink on a page. As an example, look at the differences between [American and Japanese](http://loyalkng.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/japanese-versus-usa-america-Navy-Recruitment-Commercials-emoticons.gif) emoticons. The American icons tend to focus on the mouth, while the Japanese icons focus on the eyes. If I didn't know it was on a chart of emoticons, I wouldn't even see that (^3^) was supposed to be a face.

When we talk about illegible writing, we mean we can't figure out what basic symbols are on the page. When we talk about "illegible" drawings, we often are talking about a totally different "language" of art that we just don't know the rules to.